# mysql - fill field by other fields

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a birthdate, year, month, day columns where columns "year,month,day" are foreign key to other tables
What I want to do is for each birthdate get id(year(birthdate)) to be the value of year column and the same thing for month and day columns.

How can I do this in MySQL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the use case for splitting a date into 3 columns?

Answer (score 2):

```
Update mytable
set birthdate = Yearfield + monthfield + dayfield
```

**EDIT**

If birthdate is a date field you will have to cast or convert it first.

```
Update mytable
    set birthdate = Cast(Yearfield + monthfield + dayfield as date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out triggers (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) so every time the data is written you calculate and update the information you require.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
update tableName set birthdate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
```

Comment: Typo in there Manrico - two months.